# Change width of g element (and all its content) to fit exactly SVG width

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I'm working on a program that dynamically generate svgs like this :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="330.75" height="41.91000000000008" viewBox="0 0 330.75 41.91" xml:space="preserve">
   <desc>Created with Fabric.js 2.4.3</desc>
   <defs></defs>
   <g transform="matrix(6.75 0 0 1.27 165.38 20.96)">
     <rect style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(25, 205, 255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 50px 0px; transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0px);" x="-24" y="-16" rx="0" ry="0" width="48" height="32"></rect>
   </g>
</svg>
```

When using jQuery, to determine the width of svg and g element, I get this:

```
$('svg')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width = 802.79

$('svg > g')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width = 786.33
```

I want the g element's width to fit exactly the width of svg. Please, how can I make that happen ?

I tried something as follow:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="330.75" height="41.91000000000008" viewBox="0 0 330.75 41.91" xml:space="preserve">
   <desc>Created with Fabric.js 2.4.3</desc>
   <defs></defs>
   <g width="330.75" height="41.91000000000008">
     <rect style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(25, 205, 255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 50px 0px; transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0px);" x="-24" y="-16" rx="0" ry="0" width="48" height="32"></rect>
   </g>
</svg>
```

But it doesn't work, my rect lost its initial width/height, it becomes very small.

Please how can I make the g element (and all its content) width to always fit the svg width ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing the content of the g element to fit the svg you may change the svg viewBox. I've removed the transform of the svg g element. Also I've removed the height of the svg elelemt.

Instead of using `.getBoundingClientRect` for the g element you need to use `.getBBox()`. This is giving you the position and the size of the group, and you can use this data for the new value of the viewBox.

If you need a smaller height of the svg element and you don't mind the deformation you can add `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to the svg and keep the height

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="330.75" viewBox="-24 -16 48 32" xml:space="preserve">
   <desc>Created with Fabric.js 2.4.3</desc>
   <defs></defs>
   <g id="theGroup">
     <rect style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(25, 205, 255); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1; transform-origin: 50px 0px; transform: translateX(0%) translateY(0px);" x="-24" y="-16" rx="0" ry="0" width="48" height="32"></rect>
   </g>
</svg>
```